# Alternatives to "Oldest" for Sorting Order

Tags: labels, sort

I have a sort menu option labeled "Sort By Date." When that option is selected, two buttons appear for controlling the sort order.

For the button text, can anyone suggest alternatives to `Newest to Oldest` and `Oldest to Newest`?

It's the word `Oldest` that is troublesome; the items being sorted are products and `Oldest` carries a somewhat negative connotation IMO.

I've also considered `Newest First` but the reverse would be `Newest Last`, which seems awkward.

Comment: Why can you sort products chronologically? Or: When would users want to do that? Which date is used: Production? Available for sale? Added to the shop?

Comment: What's wrong with [Newest first] and [Oldest first]?

Comment: Or, if you really want to avoid the word oldest, "Newest Last" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few options:

- Forgo labels and use an up and down arrow to toggle the list. This visual metaphor is used a lot when toggle the sort order for tables.
- Remove the toggle altogether and change your initial "sort" text to "Sort by Newest" instead of "Sort by Date" and then presenting two new buttons. An example:

[image: Land's End Product Sort]

- Use *Newer* to *Older*. The *Most/Least Recent* option from **Code Maverick** was one I had also thought of as well.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's anything inherently wrong with **Newest** or **Oldest**, but here are some suggestions for both button names:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fr2ScX.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: I'd disagree. Clear and concise copy is just as essential to great experiences as elements like dropdowns, form fields, selectors and so on.

Comment: @Hynes - That's true. I removed my migration opinion.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to have the words "sort by date" and arrow to the side pointing up and down, one sorts from older to newest and the other one in reverse. You can add words to the title of the images and those words can be things like "Newest products first" and "earlier products first". This plays with the fact that the user has a higher weight for the words that he can read on the first place which are just the sort part.

The trade off is that you reduce a bit the clarity of the interaction. I definitely prefer to see clear options, and don't think that I'd have a bad perception/impression due to the wording of the sorting options. Unless you are selling fresh products and then the word oldest would be associated with almost end of life.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing what kind of products you are selling, it's my opinion that you don't need to have both **Newest** to **Oldest** or **Oldest** to **Newest**, just have **Sort by Date** or even **New** where you default to showing the newest products first.